# Im trying to change levels within my game but wont work

Tags: python, function, loops, error-handling, pygame

```
import random
import pygame
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()


# MUSIC CODE

death_Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('death.wav')
food_Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('eat.wav')
music_Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('bg.wav')
victory_Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('win.wav')

pygame.mixer.music.load('bg.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(20)

class Button():
    def __init__(self):
        self.textBoxes = {}
        
    #----Clicked In----
    def clickedIn(self,x,y,width,height):
        global mouse_state, mouse_x, mouse_y
        if mouse_state == 1 and mouse_x >= x and mouse_x <= (x + width) and mouse_y >= y and mouse_y <= (y + height):
            return True

    #----Clicked Out----
    def clickedOut(self,x,y,width,height):
        global mouse_state, mouse_x, mouse_y
        if mouse_state == 1 and mouse_x < x or mouse_state == 1 and mouse_x > (x + width) or mouse_state == 1 and mouse_y < y or mouse_state == 1 and mouse_y > (y + height):
            return True

    #----Hovering----
    def hovering(self,x,y,width,height):
        global mouse_state, mouse_x, mouse_y
        if mouse_state == 0 and mouse_x >= x and mouse_x <= (x + width) and mouse_y >= y and mouse_y <= (y + height):
            return True
    
    #----Click Button----
    def clickButton(self,x,y,width,height,normalColor,hoverColor,textFont,text,textColor,stateHolding = False,stateVariable = 0,state = 1):
        if not self.clickedIn(x,y,width,height) and not self.hovering(x,y,width,height):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,normalColor,(x,y,width,height))
        elif self.hovering(x,y,width,height):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,hoverColor,(x,y,width,height))
        if stateHolding == True and stateVariable == state:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,hoverColor,(x,y,width,height))
        buttonText = textFont.render(text,True,textColor)
        buttonText_x = buttonText.get_rect().width
        buttonText_y = buttonText.get_rect().height
        screen.blit(buttonText,(((x + (width / 2)) - (buttonText_x / 2)),((y + (height / 2)) - (buttonText_y / 2))))
        if self.clickedIn(x,y,width,height):
            return True

WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREY = (127,127,127)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
DGREEN = (0,127,0)



font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS',20)

# SCREEN/IMAGE CODE
size = (600,700)
screen_width = 600
screen_height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
ready_text = pygame.image.load('start.png')

pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
start = 3
scale = 30






screen.blit(ready_text,(screen_width/2 - 183.5,screen_height/2 -67))

class Snake():
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True
        self.length = 1
        self.tail = []
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.xV = 0
        self.yV = 1
        self.tick = 0
    
    def draw(self):
        for section in self.tail:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,(((section[0]) * scale),((section[1]) * scale) + 100,scale,scale))
    
    def update(self):
        if self.alive == True:
            if self.tick == 10:
                self.x += self.xV
                self.y += self.yV
                for segment in self.tail:
                    if segment[0] == self.x and segment[1] == self.y:
                        self.alive = False
                self.tick = 0
                self.tail.append((self.x,self.y))
            else:
                self.tick += 1
            while len(self.tail) > self.length:
                self.tail.pop(0)
        if self.x == -1:
            self.alive = False
            self.x = 0
        if self.x == (size[0] / scale):
            self.alive = False
            self.x = (size[0] / scale) - 1
        if self.y == -1:
            self.alive = False
            self.y = 0
        if self.y == (size[1] - 100) / scale:
            self.alive = False
            self.y = ((size[1] - 100) / scale) - 1
        
    def reset(self):
        self.alive = True
        self.length = 1
        self.tail.clear()
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.xV = 0
        self.yV = 1
        self.tick = 0
        

    

class Food():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange((size[0] / scale) - 1)
        self.y = random.randrange(((size[1] - 100) / scale) - 1)
    
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,((self.x * scale),(self.y * scale) + 100,scale,scale))
    
    def update(self):
        if snake.x == self.x and snake.y == self.y:
            self.reset()
            snake.length += 1
            food_Sound.play()
           
            
    
    def reset(self):
        self.x = random.randrange((size[0] / scale) - 1)
        self.y = random.randrange(((size[1] - 100) / scale) - 1)
        
class Bombs():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange((size[0] / scale) - 1)
        self.y = random.randrange(((size[1] - 100) / scale) - 1)
    
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,((self.x * scale),(self.y * scale) + 100,scale,scale))
    
    def update(self):
        if snake.x == self.x and snake.y == self.y:
            snake.alive = False
            
            
    def reset(self):
        self.x = random.randrange((size[0] / scale) - 1)
        self.y = random.randrange(((size[1] - 100) / scale) - 1)


start -= 1

def snake_win():
    snake.alive = False
    victory_Sound.play()

class Utility():
    def __init__(self):
        return
    
    def draw(self):
        text = font.render("Length: " + str(snake.length),True,BLACK)
        text_y = text.get_rect().height
        if start <= 0:
            snake.alive = False
        if (str(snake.length)) == '3':
            snake_win()
            if button.clickButton((size[0] / 2) - 75,25,150,50,GREEN,DGREEN,font,"You won!",WHITE,snake_win):
                snake.reset()
                food.reset()
                game_state.main_game2()
            return
        screen.blit(text,(90,(50 - (text_y / 2))))
        text = font.render("Alive: " + str(snake.alive),True,BLACK)
        text_y = text.get_rect().height
        screen.blit(text,(size[0] - 210,(50 - (text_y / 2))))
        pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(0,100),(size[0],100),7)
        if snake.alive == False:
            death_Sound.play()
            if button.clickButton((size[0] / 2) - 75,25,150,50,GREEN,DGREEN,font,"Play Again",WHITE):
                snake.reset()
                food.reset()
                bombs.reset()
                utility.reset()
        for i in range(int(size[0] / scale) - 1):
            pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(0,(100 + (i * scale) + scale)),(size[0],(100 + (i * scale) + scale)),3)
            pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(((i * scale) + scale),100),(((i * scale) + scale),size[1]),3)
            
    def update(self):
        return

# general callback
button = Button()
snake = Snake()
food = Food()
utility = Utility()
bombs = Bombs()



class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 'intro'
        global mouse_state, mouse_x, mouse_y
        
    def intro(self):
        global mouse_state, mouse_x, mouse_y
        screen.fill(GREY)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.state = 'main_game'
                
                
                
        screen.blit(ready_text,(screen_width/2 - 183.5,screen_height/2 -67))
        pygame.display.flip()
        
    def main_game(self):
        global mouse_state, mouse_x, mouse_y

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_state = 1
                pygame.mouse.set_pos(mouse_x,mouse_y + 1)
            else:
                mouse_state = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    snake.yV = 0
                    snake.xV = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    snake.yV = 0
                    snake.xV = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    snake.xV = 0
                    snake.yV = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    snake.xV = 0
                    snake.yV = 1
        
        mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
        mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
        
        pygame.display.set_caption("Snake, FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()))
        
        screen.fill(GREY)
        
        
        
        food.draw()
        snake.draw()
        utility.draw()
        snake.update()
        food.update()
        utility.update()
        
        pygame.display.flip()
        
    def main_game2(self):
        global mouse_state, mouse_x, mouse_y

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_state = 1
                pygame.mouse.set_pos(mouse_x,mouse_y + 1)
            else:
                mouse_state = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    snake.yV = 0
                    snake.xV = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    snake.yV = 0
                    snake.xV = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    snake.xV = 0
                    snake.yV = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    snake.xV = 0
                    snake.yV = 1
        
        mouse_x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
        mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
        
        pygame.display.set_caption("Snake, FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()))
        
        screen.fill(GREY)
        
        
        
        food.draw()
        snake.draw()
        utility.draw()
        bombs.draw()
        snake.update()
        food.update()
        utility.update()
        bombs.update()
        
        pygame.display.flip()
        
        
    def state_manager(self):
        global mouse_state, mouse_x, mouse_y
        
        if self.state == 'intro':
            self.intro()
        if self.state == 'main_game':
            self.main_game()
        if self.state == 'main_game2':
            self.main_game2()

                    
game_state = GameState()
while not done:
    game_state.state_manager()
    clock.tick(50)

pygame.quit()
```

In the utility class i called the gamestate to be maingame2 function so it would change the level to next level thats available am i missing code here or misunderstanding something because i am confused also it dosnt show an error message the thing is i do see the maingame2 function being called soon as you press the play again button but then reverts back to the first stage (maingame) not sure if its do with loops

Comment: The code in `main_game2` seems to be identical to the code in `main_game` except that `main_game2` adds bombs. Is that correct?

Comment: yes because the idea is to add progressively harder mechanics after each level

Comment: You are not changing the gamestate.  You call it as a function but don't change "self.state = 'main_game'" at any point, so it is always set to that. So state manager always sees it as "main game"

Comment: that makes abit more sense now but im not sure how i would make a condition for the selfstate to switch the next gamestate when im trying to make it trigger specifically when the game ends/ player wins when reaches the score required to win

Comment: In the utility update, check the score and change gamestate to main_game2 there.

Comment: not sure if i did it right but didnt work just ran into maximum recursion depth error

Comment: If you want a state engine and game states, I recommend using this: https://gist.github.com/iminurnamez/8d51f5b40032f106a847 - it will be much easier in the long run.  via reddir/r/pygame sub

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recursively calling `game_state.main_game2()` you need to set `game_state.state == 'main_game2'`:

```py
class Utility():
    # [...]
    
    def draw(self):
        text = font.render("Length: " + str(snake.length),True,BLACK)
        text_y = text.get_rect().height
        if start <= 0:
            snake.alive = False
        if (str(snake.length)) == '3':
            snake_win()
            if button.clickButton((size[0] / 2) - 75,25,150,50,GREEN,DGREEN,font,"You won!",WHITE,snake_win):
                snake.reset()
                food.reset()

                game_state.state = 'main_game2'
```

Comment: what should i be doing afterwards tho?